# mysql stored procedure not firing from event scheduler

Tags: mysql

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this sp. The logic seems to be ok, but when i check back in my table it doesn't work at all.

```
    DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_zero_yearly_sales_proc //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_zero_yearly_sales_proc() 
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 

DECLARE num_of_sales INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE last_ins_date DATETIME;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

SET last_ins_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR);

ins_loop: WHILE last_ins_date < NOW() DO
SELECT COUNT(sales_amount_sold) INTO num_of_sales
FROM yearly_sales
WHERE sales_date_sold BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(last_ins_date,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(last_ins_date),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59');

IF num_of_sales = 0 THEN  

INSERT INTO yearly_sales(sales_date_sold, sales_amount_sold,sales_quantity) 
VALUES (CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(last_ins_date,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01')),0, 0);

END IF ;

SET num_of_sales = 0;
SET last_ins_date = DATE_ADD(last_ins_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

END WHILE ins_loop;
SET done = 0;

END ;//
DELIMITER ;
```

I've created an event that fires every hour to call this procedure. The procedure is supposed to check if there are months in the yearly_sales table without any sales values in them, and if so add 0 values for the amount & quantity, and the beginning of the month for the date. I've checked back but it doesn't seem to work.

Also here's the event i created to call it hourly

```
    DELIMITER //  
CREATE    
EVENT `hourly_sales_evt`  
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:55:00')
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN 
    CALL add_zero_yearly_sales_proc();
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The code is supposed to go back 2 years and search each month until it reaches the current month

Comment: Have you tried invoking the procedure manually?  Does it do what it's supposed to?  That is, is your problem with the event scheduler or the procedure itself?

Comment: Oh my! it works when i call it manually. Seems it's the event that's not shooting. Thanks

Comment: I think it was a problem of the global event scheduler. Almost drove me nuts this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be global event scheduler is in stopped/disabled state.

To turn on event scheduler, run any of the following:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

When the Event Scheduler is ON, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a daemon process, and its state is represented as shown here:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: show processlist
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 2
   User: event_scheduler
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Daemon
   Time: 3
  State: Waiting for next activation
   Info: NULL
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Once the Event Scheduler is set ON, you would see it working.

**Refer to** : [MySQL Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

The procedure looks OK, the logic should work. But, I want to ask you - why do you check `sales_date_sold` from first second -`DATE_FORMAT(last_ins_date,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01')`, shouldn't it be DATE_FORMAT(last_ins_date,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')?

Another point: you execute SELECT statement many times in the loop, it is not effective. Try to create additional (maybe temporary table) with month numbers and join two tables to find out months without any sales. In this case you will achieve result in one step.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the time. Even though select statments are executed many times, i don't think it will affect performance in any way since it's fired from the background as an event.

Comment: You will skip records with `sales_date_sold` values like this - '2010-06-01 00:00:00', because your condition is '2010-06-01 00:00:01'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here without doing much digging, but I think this is your issue:

```
READS SQL DATA
...
INSERT INTO yearly_sales(sales_date_sold, sales_amount_sold,sales_quantity) 
VALUES (CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(last_ins_date,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:01')),0, 0);
```